# BlackBerry Debug Output

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

The BlackBerry Simulator outputs tons of information to Eclipse's console when running debug mode.  Is there anyway to filter what information is displayed ?

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking into it and the option doesn't seem to be available in Eclipse.  It is definitely there in the JDE (Edit -> Preferences -> Debug Tab -> Display Tab -> "Log debug strings to output window" checkbox).

I would consider querying the [BlackBerry developer forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/?category.id=BlackBerryDevelopment) or dropping and email to devsupport@rim.com requesting that this option be exposed in the Eclipse BlackBerry plugin.

Comment: But even that does not give very much granularity over what is to be showed, right?